# Angular 6 получение данных

Tags: angular5

Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть web api на c#, который возвращает модель аккаунта по его айди, это все хорошо, но я не могу эти данные перекинуть в переменную в angular, то есть.

```
public account: Account; // переменная куда кидаем

ngOnInit() {
    this.accountService.getById(1).subscribe(
      (data: Account) => {
        console.log(data); // возвращает массив 
        this.account = data; // пытаемся присвоить, если я тут же закину вывод в консоль, то все пройдет, но дальше переменная пустая.
      },
      error => console.log(error) 
    );
    this.initForm();
    console.log(this.account); // возвращает ничего в консоль, просто нет данных
  }

getById(id: number): Observable<Account> {
    return this.http.get<Account>(this.url + "/" + id);
  } // так я получаю данные
```

Comment: Что у Вас в `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Просто для проверки, приходят ли данные или нет, они поступают, но например обратиться к определенному полю data.name он не дает, говорит не существует, хотя в модели такое поле есть

Comment: Почитайте про асинхронность в `js`.

Comment: Я понимаю, но дело в том, что данные приходят, но я не могу обратиться к их полям или же перекинуть в другую переменную

Comment: @Евгений, слушайте ораторов выше - читайте про асинхронность, `this.account = data` сеттится после `console.log(this.account);`

Comment: Даже если вывожу данные на форму, просто пустота выходит.

Comment: Судя из кода, вывод в форму у Вас какой-то свой, через initForm?
Если да, то Ваш подход в корне не верный, о чем Вам пытаются донести.

Comment: Это просто сделайте так: добавьте initForm() в subscribe
`this.accountService.getById(1).subscribe(
      (data: Account) => {
        console.log(data); // возвращает массив 
        this.account = data;
        this.initForm();
      },
      error => console.log(error) 
    );`